# How to set filters in React Konvajs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, konvajs, konva, konvajs-reactjs

I have SVG images and I need to change their color. If I work with usual HTML elements, I use function which converts hex to CSS filters.
For example '#b5b5b5' is the same as 'invert(51%) sepia(81%) saturate(1433%) hue-rotate(195deg) brightness(100%) contrast(93%)'. So if my SVG was black it becomes blue.

[image]

How can I do the same with Konva?
I've tried to apply filters as they did it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/konvajs/site/tree/master/react-demos/filters?from-embed=&file=/src/index.js), but I got wrong colors. Can you show me a working example with react and the filters I wrote above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Konva filters doesn't follow CSS specification for filters. Konva filters may have different behavior and accept different arguments.  So, it may be hard to reproduce the same result using built-in filters.

You have two options:

#### 1. Custom filter.

Following [Custom Filter Tutorial](https://konvajs.org/docs/filters/Custom_Filter.html), you can write your filter function and manipulate pixels as you like it. For you use case, you can simplify the logic a lot. For example, just replace pixels with some color by a pixel with another color.

*You can 100% replace all CSS filters here, but it is not a trivial work.*

```js
// lets define a custom filter:
var ColorReplaceFilter = function (imageData) {
  var nPixels = imageData.data.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < nPixels - 4; i += 4) {
    const isTransparent = imageData.data[i + 3] === 0;
    if (!isTransparent) {
      imageData.data[i] = 90;
      imageData.data[i + 1] = 149;
      imageData.data[i + 2] = 246;
    }
  }
};

const CustomFilterImage = () => {
  const [image] = useImage(URL, "Anonimus");
  const imageRef = React.useRef();
  // when image is loaded we need to cache the shape
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (image) {
      // you many need to reapply cache on some props changes like shadow, stroke, etc.
      imageRef.current.cache();
    }
  }, [image]);

  return (
    <Image
      ref={imageRef}
      x={100}
      y={10}
      image={image}
      filters={[ColorReplaceFilter]}
      blurRadius={10}
    />
  );
};
```

#### 2. `context.filter` API.

You can use [CanvasRenderingContext2D.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter) property to apply CSS filters on canvas element. For the demo, I will draw an image into external canvas to apply filters just on it instead of the whole Konva Layer.

**Be careful, at the time of writing this answer, the API is not supported in all browsers!**

```js
const FilterViaCanvasImage = () => {
  const [image] = useImage(URL, "Anonimus");

  const canvas = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (!image) {
      return undefined;
    }
    const el = document.createElement("canvas");

    el.width = image.width;
    el.height = image.height;
    const ctx = el.getContext("2d");
    ctx.filter =
      "invert(51%) sepia(81%) saturate(1433%) hue-rotate(195deg) brightness(100%) contrast(93%)";
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    return el;
  }, [image]);

  return (
    <Image
      x={10}
      y={10}
      image={canvas}
      filters={[Konva.Filters.HSV]}
      hue={110}
      saturation={10}
      value={100}
    />
  );
};
```

Demo for the both cases: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-color-replace-filters-fqy2q